# Add to json object order

Tags: php, json

Is there a way to write to a json object in the beginning and not the end? When I add now its putting it on the bottom. I need it on the top because the newest data is in the beginning.

```
<?php
    $file = file_get_contents('./data.json');
    $data = json_decode($file);
    unset($file);
    $data[] = array('data'=>'some data');
    file_put_contents('data.json',json_encode($data));
    unset($data);
```

Comment: post some code if you can

Comment: just make sure to make the current values an array, then just shift it back then reencode again, or maybe push it inside then resort if there is a date involved

Comment: To add to @Ghost's comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that simple case above, like @jeroen said in the comments, you could use `array_unshift()` for this purpose:

So lets say initially we have `data.json` with contents like this:

```
[{"data":"somedata 1"},{"data":"somedata 2"},{"data":"somedata 3"}]
```

And you want to prepend values to it.

```
$file = file_get_contents('data.json'); // get the file
$data = json_decode($file, true); // turn it into an array (true flag)
unset($file);
// $data[] = array('data'=>'some data');
// Don't use this, this will append/push the data in the end
array_unshift($data, array('data' => 'some data 4')); // unshift it
file_put_contents('data.json',json_encode($data)); // put it back together again
unset($data);
```

So finally, you'll have something like this:

```
[{"data":"some data 4"},{"data":"somedata 1"},{"data":"somedata 2"},{"data":"somedata 3"}]
```

<sub>*Note: Asumming you have the right permissions.*</sub>